# Does anyone know how to store a css change made by javascript function locally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, local-storage

I have been scratching my head for a while, and I can't figure out how I could locally store (HTML5 local storage) a change to the styling of a certain div made by a javascript function. I have a button which allows the user to change the background colour of the container by changing the css (inline). Does anyone know of a way of storing this change?

Comment: The same way you would store anything else in local storage.

Comment: Now is the div identified?

Comment: As you've pointed out, just use local storage. Put an indicator in local storage which you'll have to check everytime the page loads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4U7ky/)

JS (running at `load` or `DOMContentLoaded`):

```
var bgColor = document.getElementById('bgcolor');
bgColor.onchange = function() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = this.value;
    localStorage.setItem('bgColor', this.value);
};
bgColor.value = localStorage.getItem('bgColor');
bgColor.onchange();
```

HTML:

```
<input id="bgcolor" />
```

---

Or, if you use jQuery,

```
$('#bgcolor')
    .val(localStorage.getItem('bgColor'))
    .change(function() {
        $('body').css({'background-color': this.value});
        localStorage.setItem('bgColor', this.value);
    })
    .change();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4U7ky/1/)

Answer (score 2):

So you have a function like:

```
function changeDivBackground(div, bg) {
    /* ...change the background... */
}
```

There are two steps:

1. Remember the value:

   ```
   function changeDivBackground(div, bg) {
       /* ...change the background... */

       localStorage["theDivBackground"] = bg;
   }
   ```
2. In a `script` tag at the end of the page, see if you have a value and use it:

   ```
   var bg = localStorage["theDivBackground"];
   if (bg) {
       changeDivBackground(/*...get the div...*/, bg);
   }
   ```

The `script` tag is at the *end* of the page in #2 so that the div will exist by the time it's run.

Answer (score -1):

Store the value to local storage. Then write a JavaScript function that retrieves the value and applies it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am very new to the Javascript Language. Could you explain that in more detail?